# How can I save application state to cookies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, react-hooks

I am currently working on a simple Tetris game, realized in ReactJS. I am using useState() hook to manage components' state. Fundamental feature of this app, besides being playable is to give users a chance to continue the game even after closing the app. ( App will be deployed on GitHub pages ). Could you give me any suggestion how Can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Use js-cookies to set state to cookies and on component mount use useEffect to retrieve those cookies and set your state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save state in a Cookie, you most probably need to install a dependency like [universal-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-cookie).

However, you can use `localStorage` which doesn't require external dependencies.

**Usage**

To save data:

```js
const dataToStore = { ... }
localStorage.setItem("storedData", JSON.stringify(dataToStore));
```

To retrieve data:

```js
const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("storedData"));
```

Comment: I would like to ask the user if she/he wants to continue the game ( if any continuation is possible ). Then to get Data from eg. local storage.  Should I get these items ( component state or variables ) in ComponentDidMount()?

Comment: Yes, you can get those in `componentDidMount()`

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do this :)

Comment: My Component is functional Component, where I use custom hooks also.  I Can retrieve data inside useEffect() after if condition satisfied - user wants to continue the game. But where is the place to put this data into local storage to be sure, that they are actual?